# Uncaught TypeError: PouchDB.plugin is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack, browser, pouchdb

When i execute the code belove, this error shows up: Uncaught TypeError: PouchDB.plugin is not a function. If i install the pouchdb package from npm and change the first line accordingly, then the plugin part works but if i want to use a function from pouchdb-authentication i getting a function not found error.

```
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb-browser');

let auth = require('pouchdb-authentication');

PouchDB.plugin(auth);
```

The code should execute without errors and the functions from the authentication plugin should work.

Comment: I use vanilla javascript (es8) with webpack

Comment: Have you had success with other plugins; "find" for example?

Comment: I tried it now. same result with pouchdb-browser, "PouchDB.plugin is not a function". Maybe its a problem with webpack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with replacing the code this way:

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import auth from 'pouchdb-authentication';
PouchDB.plugin(auth);
```

Now it works without problems

Answer (score 1):

use default

for browser or use cdn link

```
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb-browser').default;
```

for node

```
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb').default;
```